# Why does extending the time domain of a signal with a fft introduce a fade out and fade in?

Tags: fft, audio

I was playing around with FFTs and decided to try extending the time domain of the original signal. I did this through taking an FFT to the frequency domain, doubling the amount of samples by averaging every two samples, and then taking IFFT back to the time domain.

This repeated the signal (and probably changed the phase relationships somewhat), which is understandable. However, it also introduced a fadeout throughout the first sample and a fade in throughout the second. When I trippled the amount of samples, two fade-in-fade-out pairs were introduced and the behavior of each remains the same. Why does the fade happen?

[image: waveforms]

code and audio files: https://github.com/echometerain/sound-derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two FFT properties at work here.

Just for convenience, let $x_n$ be your original signal, and $X_k$ be its DFT (remember that an FFT is just a fast way to implement the discrete Fourier transform -- what I have to say applies to *any* discrete Fourier transform, so I'm going to use "DFT" here).

The two properties are:

1. If you take $X_k$ and upsample it; i.e. let $^2X_k = \begin{bmatrix}X_0 & 0 & X_1 & 0 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$, then its inverse Fourier transform, $^2 x_n = \mathcal F^{-1} \{^2 X\}$, will be $x_n$ repeated twice: $^2 x_n = \begin{bmatrix}x & x\end{bmatrix}$.
2. If you take *any* signal $Y$ in the frequency domain and convolve it by $X$, and take the inverse Fourier transform, then the result will be the point-by-point multiplication of the inverse Fourier transforms of each: $\mathcal F^{-1}\{X \star Y\} = F^{-1}\{X\}F^{-1}\{Y\}$

   1. Note that for a DFT, the convolution is circular.

We can take your problem and make it fit these properties.

Observe that making $\begin{bmatrix}X_0 & X_0 & X_1 & X_1 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$ is *mathematically identical* to convolving $X_k$ with $Y_k = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$.

So when you do that, the result of your IFFT is your original signal, repeated, *and multiplied by the IFFT of that $Y_k$*.  The IFFT of $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$ is what provides the fading in your example -- the IFFT of three ones in a row followed by zeros is similar, and so causes similar fading in your second example.

Comment: `conv([1 2 3],[1 1 0 0])  = [1     3     5     3     0     0]` which is not `[1 1 2 2 3 3]` ? Looks more like a kronecker product to me.

Comment: You're missing the resampling (and the fact that it's the _circular_ convolution -- but I may not have mentioned that).  $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 3 & 0\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: OK, but this isn't true: Observe that making $\begin{bmatrix}X_0 & X_0 & X_1 & X_1 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$ is _mathematically identical_ to convolving $X_k$ with $Y_k = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\end{bmatrix}$.  Should probably say "upsampled $X_k$" or something to make it clear. I lost the connection, so others will too.

Comment: Tim, might it be as good or better to use the O&S convention with $X[k]$ instead of $X_k$?

Comment: @PeterK. He's convolving $Y_k$ with $X_k$ that's zero-inserted and twice as long.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I understand. That's not what the text I quoted says.